# How much health do bosses have?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Not only the Calamity Ganon, but I’m also wondering about Ganon blights, different forms of Hinox, Talus, Molduga, Lynel, Master Kohga and Maz Koshia?

Comment: Did you attempt at solving this question yourself before asking? A quick google search for "breath of the wild molduga health" directed me to the [BotW Wiki](https://zelda.gamepedia.com/Molduga), which states that a Molduga has 1500 HP. Please put in some effort before asking questions.

Comment: @MechMK1 a well formatted question (and this one could certainly use some clarification and clean up) that asks for possibly already well-known data, but presented in a new way, is absolutely a valid one. A short search does not seem to bring up a list in one place of every boss in the game's health, so an answer such as bearb001's is indeed a great resource for someone trying to compare all the bosses or something else like that.

Comment: @Tylor Valid point. I'm not completely aware of how Arqade handles low-effort questions, and so my comment was from the point that other sites hold.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [Zelda wiki site](http://zelda.gamepedia.com), bosses have these values for health:

- Talus:

  - Normal: 300
  - Luminous: 600
  - Rare: 900
  - Frost: 800
  - igneo: 800
  - igneo Talus Titan: ?
- Stalnox: 1000
- Hinox

  - Red: 600
  - Blue: 800 <sub>(14 hits with fully powered master sword)</sub>
  - Black: 1000 <sub>(17 hits with fully powered master sword)</sub>
- Lynels

  - Normal: 2000
  - Blue-Maned: 3000
  - White-Maned: 4000
  - Silver-Maned: 5000
- Guardians:

  - Decayed: 500
  - Turret: 1500
  - Stalker: 1500
  - Skywatcher: 1500
- Molduga: 1500
- Molduking: 1500 (this feels incorrect, please someone confirm this)
- Calamity Ganon: 8000 
  <sub>(32 hits with fully powered master sword, one head shot with a 26-bow for the first phase after doing all 4 divine beasts, I probably lost track and forgot to count one attack with the master sword)</sub>
- Ganon Blights

  - Water: 1500 <sub>(35 hits with 22-weapon for each of two phases)</sub>
  - Fire: 1500 <sub>(13 hits with 60-weapon for first phase, 1 bomb+, 12 hits with 60-weapon for second phase)</sub>
  - Wind: 1500 <sub>(27 hits with 10-weapon (27th hit broke it), 12 hits in the eye with a 20-bow for the first phase, the bow ended that phase)</sub>
  - Thunder: 1500 <sub>(24 hits with 32-weapon for the first phase, 20 regular hits and 2 hits that looked like they did more damage in the second phase)</sub>
- Master Kohga: ?
- Monk Maz Koshia: 4000 <sub>(17 hits with fully powered master sword for each of four phases)</sub>

*Note: I didn't find all the health values in the wiki, I tested the ones I didn't find within the game and put detailed information on what I did next to the health number, the health number is an educated guess in those cases (the last hit may not be fully required) and can be slightly off.*

*Note 2: The bosses with question marks did not have any health value in the wiki and it would take too long for me to reach those within the game to test it, because they are permanently defeated in my save file; I may add those later.*

*Note 3: I fought the ganon blights through the DLC, they may have different health values there, but it should be the same.*

Comment: Just adding a bit more information: Blight Ganons' health increases depending on how many divine beasts you are done with. first one has 800, next 1200, next 1600 and finally 2000.

Answer (score 2):

The Ganon Blights have varying HP going from 800 HP to 2000, depending on how many you have fought before, but they all have 1500 in the Illusory Realm. The Lynels have: red 2000, blue 3000, white-maned 4000 and silver 6000.

All info is confirmed by the complete official guide, expanded edition.

Comment: master kohga has 300 hp btw

Comment: you can [edit that in here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/381290/edit)